# How to use the Express router to redirect a URL?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have the following two domains:

- myVeryLongSiteDomain.com
- mVeryShortURL.co

**I need the following short URLs:**

- mVeryShortURL.com/123456789
- mVeryShortURL.com/a-DSa131_

**To redirect to the long site domain like so:**

- myVeryLongSiteDomain.com/**feedback**/123456789
- myVeryLongSiteDomain.com/**feedback**/a-DSa131_

My node/express server running mVeryShortURL.co has the following in the web.js for routing:

```
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.redirect(newBaseURL + request.url);
});
```

How can I update the above to add `/feedback/` to the url path when the url matches the short url pattern above (7 alphanumeric characters): A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just string manipulation and you can put the `/feedback` into the newBaseURL and to only do that when you have 7 characters of `A-Z a-z 0-9` as the path, you can just make a regex for that route and when it matches that route, you add the `/feeback` to the URL, and for all other routes you don't.

```
let newBaseURL = 'http://myVeryLongSiteDomain.com';

app.get(/\/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]{7}/, function(request, response) {
  response.redirect(newBaseURL + '/feedback' + request.url);
});

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.redirect(newBaseURL + request.url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to match for the 7 characters and only add the path when it matches but not in the other cases?

Comment: @AnApprentice - I don't understand what the pattern is you want to match?

Comment: Example, if the user went to the shortURL without anything in the path, it would then redirect without adding `/feedback`

Comment: Pattern is `/` proceeded by `7 alphanumberic characters): A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _-` ,  only when that matches add `/feedback/` otherwise, just redirect to the base url

Comment: @AnApprentice - OK, I'm working on that.  Didn't follow that from your question originally.

Comment: see above, does that make sense?

Comment: very nice, thank you. FYI, I think you missed a ' `app.get('`

Comment: @AnApprentice - OK, I added a regex for 7 alpha numerics.

Comment: oh wait, will that also support `_` and `-` ?

Comment: @AnApprentice - Didn't see those chars in the requirements.  I added them to the regex.